# How to register twig filter into Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, yaml, symfony4

I have a problem of registration with my custom twig extension in Symfony 4 .
I have create extension who help me to decode my json data but it's not work.
This message is display when I want to use my json_decode filter.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZEP7.png)

The code of my custom twig filter :

```
<?php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getName() {
        return 'Json Decode';
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('json_decode', [$this, 'json_decode']),
        ];
    }

    public function json_decode($input, $assoc = false) {
       return json_decode($input,$assoc);
    }
}
?>
```

Here is a twig_exension.yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        public: false
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    # Uncomment any lines below to activate that Twig extension
    #Twig\Extensions\ArrayExtension: null
    #Twig\Extensions\DateExtension: null
    Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension: null
    Twig\Extensions\TextExtension: null
    App\Twig\AppExtension: null
```

Here is the line that return and error in my twig file

```
{% set commande = render(controller('App\\Controller\\StoreController::getProduitsCommandes')) | json_decode  %}
```

Here is the Response return in StoreController.php

```
$response = new Response(json_encode(["produits"=>$produitsArray,"total_ht"=>$total_ht,"tva"=>$tva,"nbre_produits"=>$nbre_produits]));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

When I type **php bin/console debug:twig --filter=json_decode**
The debugger return me this result

```
---------

* json_decode(input, assoc = false)
```

Thank you for your attention
If any people has a solution it will help me

Comment: You have declared a function name which is already a php function ( json_decode() ) that may be error prone. You better try first by changing it something like custom_json_encode()

Comment: new TwigFilter('decodeit', [$this, 'doJsonDecode']),

Comment: first of remove your getName method in to AppExtension class and clear here what you exactly want twig filter or function because you write here filter is not working and you declare a getFunctions method in your AppExtension class please clear so i can help you properly

Comment: @Theva - That is incorrect, you certainly can register the functions with the same name. As seen in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters)

Comment: Thank you for all. The answer is on the bottom of this document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the errors states the `filter` can not be found. This is due to the fact you are trying to register your `filter` as a function, move the registration to the `getFilters` method instead. Also it's perfectly viable to chain existing functions

```
<?php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('json_decode', 'json_decode'), //just chain to existing PHP function
        ];
    }
}
```

---

*sidenote* The method `getName` is now obsolete and can be removed as it has been deprecated and isn't used anymore in the code

[source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/deprecated.html#extensions)